# How to delete object in a dict by reference from another variable

Tags: python

So I have nested dictionary objects

```
a = {'a':{'b':[1,2,3]}}
```

And I have a reference to the nested 'b':

```
c=a['a']['b']
```

Now when I call

```
del c
print a
```

The results are

```
{'a':{'b':[1,2,3]}}
```

The variable c is deleted but the object it referenced still exists. I want to delete the nested 'b' object altogether. It is easy to do this with

```
del a['a']['b']
```

But in the real application of this, the nesting is too deep and this is used too often for that to be feasible.

The question: How do I delete a dictionary tag with only a reference to it in another variable?

Comment: `del` deletes the named reference; you cannot delete *other* references with it, such as the one stored for `a['a']['b']`. You'll have to store a 'path', resolve all of that path *except for the last element*, then delete that reference.

Comment: If you know ``c`` without knowing ``'a'`` and ``'b'`` the solution of Martijn isn't applicable. And if you know ``'a'`` and ``'b'``, what is the benefit provided by its solution on the use of ``a['a']['b']`` ? There's something I don't understand....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`del` deals with the provided reference *only*; it cannot remove references to the same value elsewhere. That's not how Python works.

Store the *path* in the nested structure:

```
path = ('a', 'b')
```

You can resolve such a path:

```
def resolve_path(dictionary, path):
    return reduce(dict.get, path, dictionary)
```

or you can get the *parent*, after which you can delete the last element:

```
def del_endpoint(dictionary, path):
    parent_path, last = path[:-1], path[-1]
    parent = resolve_path(dictionary, parent_path)
    del parent[last]
```

This is of course very specific to nested dictionaries; for attributes or list items you'll need additional code.

Comment: Excellent, I like the creative use of the reduce function. Thanks!

Comment: @Martijn, I like your answer. @Mozoby, please consider the "orphaned reference" case if you store paths. If you keep a reference *and* a path as Martijn suggests then you risk inconsistency. An example: if the path `('a','b')` is stored and if `c=a['a']['b']`, and then this happens: `a['a']['b']=[10,20,30]`...  now the path will point to the new list `[10,20,30]` while `c` is still the old list `[1,2,3]`.  So a `del_endpoint` will work correctly but it will not affect the orphaned reference `c` or its contents. This is all we can hope for in Python.